# How to change only target icons OnClick?

Tags: jquery

I have a slidePanelExtender and 3 icons on the page. When the user clickes on the down arrow I want it to change up arrow and open the slide panel. if slide panel is open when up arrow is clicked I want it to change back to down arrow.

icons on the page is in the following code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="float: right; font-size: medium; color:#34495e"></span>



<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="slidePanelExtender" runat="Server" TargetControlID="contentAdSearch"
                        ExpandControlID="titleAdSearch" CollapseControlID="titleAdSearch" Collapsed="True"
                        SuppressPostBack="False" BehaviorID="slidePanelBehavior" />
                    <div class="adsearchbar">
                        <asp:Panel ID="titleAdSearch" runat="server" CssClass="titleAdSearch" onClick="changeArrow();">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="float: right;
                                    font-size: medium" id="arrow"></span>

                        </asp:Panel>
```

I wrote the following jquery code to onClick event.

```
 function changeArrow() {
        if ($('.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')) {
            $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
        else if ($('.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-up')) {
            $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        }
```

but it changes all icons to up arrow icon beacuse their class is 'glyphicon' too. What should I do to just change target icon?

Comment: where's your event binding part..?

Comment: **$('.glyphicon, .glyphicon-chevron-down')**
or 
**$('.glyphicon, .glyphicon-chevron-left')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function changeArrow(elem) {
        if ($(elem).find('.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')) {
            $(elem).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
        else if ($(elem).find('.glyphicon').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-up')) {
            $(elem).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        }
```

and use `onclick=changeArrow(this)`

Comment: thank you but It didn't work. the icon didn't change.

Comment: I used $(elem).find as you write.

Comment: I don't know what did I do wrong at first time but now it works. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't form a selector for just that icon, add something to it (typically a class or ID) so that you can. For instance, you might add the class up-arrow, and then:

```
$('.iconUpDown').click(function () {
   //  ^  common class 
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up);
 });
```

:**note** Actually i don't know how did you bind the event but any way try like this

Comment: Good point, the OP did say the user was clicking the icon. But "try this" followed by code is not really useful. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the icon, you have to reset the css property of it.. Whenever you toggleClass, it resets all other styles as well.. Then followed by the prefentDefault(); to prevent all default click behaviour

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function (event) {
    $(this).css('', '');

    event.preventDefault();
});
```